# How to configure a radius server for WLAN (PEAP) in Android12?

Tags: wi-fi

After having upgraded my mobile phone from Android 8 to Android 12 I realized that the WLAN settings are different.
Specifically I find no way to configure a radius server for the domain when using 802.1x EAP (PEAP).

Why can't I enter a radius server for the domain any more?

Answer (score 1):

There never was a "RADIUS server" field in Android, and there could not have been, as the client device does not speak RADIUS in the first place and cannot influence the server that will be used – it's the access points that relay the EAP messages from clients over RADIUS (or over a different protocol, or even implements EAP internally, as hostapd might do).

What Android *did* have was the "Domain" field which is used for verifying the PEAP server certificate's CN/SAN, and this field still exists in Android 12 – although it only appears after you select something from the "CA certificates" dropdown (e.g. "Use system certificates" if your network uses public web CAs for PEAP):

[image]

The "Domain" field is used like wpa_supplicant's `domain_suffix_match=` and accepts a suffix for the certificate's CN/SAN, e.g. a SAN of "radius1.example.com" would be matched either by the exact `radius1.example.com` or by the suffix `example.com`.

Comment: When I try; I see these fields (cannot make a screenshot for security reasons, BTW): "EAP Method" (PEAP), "Phase 2-Authentication" (MSCHAPV2), "CA Certificate" (Some CA, System Certificates *not* being offered), "Identity" (blank yet), "Anonymous Identity" (blak yet), and finally "Password" (blank yet). **Nothing more**. On the old phone I had "Domain" before "Identity".

Comment: If "System Certificates" isn't in the list at all (regardless of whether it would be suitable or not), I'm tempted to guess that the option was hidden by some kind of custom security policy, *and* that the domain field was hidden by the same security policy as well. (Hopefully the policy sets it to the correct value.)

Comment: As it's my own new device, I wonder where such settings could be hidden. I realized that in new Android the WLAN certificates are different from system certificates.